# throw new Error('Options must be an object, got "' + options + '"');

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error:
**throw new Error('Options must be an object, got "' + options + '"');**

for this part of my code:

```
async postRegister(req, res) {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body
        //Validate the request
        if (!name || !email || !password) {
            req.flash('error', 'All fields are required')
            req.flash('name', name)
            req.flash('email', email)
            return res.redirect('/register')
        }

        // check if email exist
        User.exists({ email: email }, (err, result) => {
            if (result) {
                req.flash('error', 'Email already register')
                req.flash('name', name)
                req.flash('email', email)
                return res.redirect('/register')
            }

        })

        //hash password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

        // Create a User
        const user = new user({
            name,
            email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        user.save().then((user)=>{
            //Login
            return res.redirect('/')
        }).catch(err =>{
            req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong')
            return res.redirect('/register')
        })

        console.log(req.body)
    }
```

Can anyone help me out ! What went wrong

I am trying to create a register section on my website. When I fill all the fields the page should be redirected to the home page. Instead, it's giving error

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Client or server? Typically, the error stack has more details - so, try to post the entire error in your question post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from Mongoose, you're using `Model.exists()` method but you're providing the wrong parameters to it, check the method document, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.exists()

Instead of the callback function, you should provide an options object, Mongoose documentation for the options object, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.setOptions()

If you're interested if the email is already registered in your database, you can `await` the `Model.exists()`. If there is no such document in your database you will get `null`, otherwise the document will be returned,

```
// check if email exist
const user = await User.exists({ email: email });
if (user) {
  req.flash('error', 'Email already register');
  req.flash('name', name);
  req.flash('email', email);
  return res.redirect('/register');
}
```